# In 2 Chronicles 33:4 what does it mean that YHVH "my name will remain in Jerusalem forever"?

Tags: temple, 2-chronicles, second-temple-judaism

> [2Ch 33:4 NLT] (4) He built pagan altars in the Temple of the LORD, the place where the LORD had said, **"My name will remain in Jerusalem forever."**
>
> > WLC 
> >     וּבָנָ֥ה מִזְבְּחֹ֖ות בְּבֵ֣ית יְהוָ֑ה אֲשֶׁר֙ אָמַ֣ר יְהוָ֔ה בִּירוּשָׁלִַ֥ם יִֽהְיֶה־שְּׁמִ֖י לְעֹולָֽם׃
> >
> > Rahlfs
> >     καὶ ᾠκοδόμησεν θυσιαστήρια ἐν οἴκῳ κυρίου οὗ εἶπεν κύριος **ἐν Ιερουσαλημ ἔσται τὸ ὄνομά μου εἰς τὸν αἰῶνα**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jerusalem was not the only thing to bear the name of YHWH.  Certainly, Jehovah makes a fuss about His name in places like Jer 16:21, Isa 42:8, etc.  But the way the OT uses this idea reveals that the Name of God was much more about character than the actual name.

- the Jews forget God's name by engaging in Baal worship Jer 23:27
- God's name was to be honoured among the nations, that is His character Mal 1:11
- The Temple in Jerusalem was bear the Name of God  1 Kings 5:5, 2 Chron 7:16, Jer 34:15, 7:30 - a place where God's goodness and righteousness was revealed
- God wants to teach the Jews about His power and might - then they will know His Name Jer 16:21
- God's character as revealed in His righteousness and healing Mal 4:2
- Ex 34:5-7 The LORD descended in the cloud and stood there with him as he called upon the **name of the LORD**. Then the LORD passed by in front of him and proclaimed, “The LORD, the LORD God, compassionate and gracious, slow to anger, and abounding in lovingkindness and truth; 7who keeps lovingkindness for thousands, who forgives iniquity …
- Shiloh was the first place where God's Name was shown Jer 7:12
- Jerusalem was the place where God's Name was to have been known - where righteous kings should have ruled forever 2 Chron 6:6
- The Israelites were the people who knew God's Name and should have behaved like it but did not Isa 52:6
- The Israelites were supposed to be called by the Name of God and thus reflect the character of God 2 Chron 7:14 - see also Jer 7:30, Dan 9:19, etc.

Thus, Jerusalem should have had the Name of God in it forever, but the people were wicked and abandoned God and the rest is history.